# Get Values from Enum Known Only At Runtime

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I need to get all the values from an enum, whose type will only be known at runtime. I've come up with the following, but would like to know if anyone knows a better way:

```
enum TestEnum  {
  FOO,
  BAR
}

Enum[] getValuesForEnum(Class type) {
  try {
    Method m = type.getMethod("values");
    return (Enum[])m.invoke(null);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

Class testEnum = Class.forName("TestEnum");
getValuesForEnum(testEnum);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all, I missed that on the API!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the available API instead:

```
T[] getValuesForEnum(Class<T> type) {
  return type.getEnumConstants();
}
```

From [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29):

> Returns the elements of this enum class or null if this Class object does not represent an enum type.

Note that I have turned your method into generic to make it typesafe. This way you need no downcasts to get the actual enum values from the returned array. (Of course, this makes the method so trivial that you can omit it and call `type.getEnumConstants()` directly :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a variant of [Kevin Stembridge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783543/get-values-from-enum-known-only-at-runtime/4783628#4783628) that preserves the type (avoiding downcasts), whilst still guarding against being called with a non-enum type:

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> E[] getValuesForEnum(Class<E> clazz) {
    return clazz.getEnumConstants();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use type.getEnumConstants().

Answer (score 3):

I think this works:

```
Enum<?>[] getValuesForEnum(Class<Enum<?>> enumType) {
    return enumType.getEnumConstants();
}
```

Comment: Nice idea to try to ensure type safety at compile time. Although, I am afraid, at the cost of requiring downcast(s) to access the returned enum values.

Comment: True, but I got the impression from his question that he would be dealing with unknown enum types. So I imagine he's going to be assigning the result of the method call to Enum<?>.