# How do I access the values of any known enum at run-time when passed a String value for the enumeration?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I need to write a service level api that exposes any enumeration at run-time. The name of the enum will be passed as a string parameter to the service layer. So that means I need to use reflection.

All of the answers I've found so far deal with knowing ahead of time the name of the enumeration.

1. I will have a string that holds the name of the enum.
2. Look up the enum using reflection (somehow).
3. Return string representations of the values associated with the enum

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783543/get-values-from-enum-known-only-at-runtime ?

Comment: So use reflection with the string to find the enum in the first place, then use that suggestion. Hmm. Ok. Something to work with. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Values from Enum Known Only At Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783543/get-values-from-enum-known-only-at-runtime)

Comment: Its close, but in my case I have a String as input. I'll go with whatever you guys suggest though for duplication marking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
package demo;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // ClassNotFoundException thrown when demo.Color does not exist
        Class<?> enumType = Class.forName("demo.Color");

        // constants is null when demo.Color is not an enum
        Object[] constants = enumType.getEnumConstants();

        System.out.println("is " + enumType + " an enum? " + enumType.isEnum());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(constants));
    }
}

enum Color {
    GREEN,
    BLUE
}
```

Comment: Works. Thank you. Once I finish I'll come back and give credit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> getValues(final String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<E> lst = null;
        if(className != null) {
            Class<E> clazz = Class.forName(className);
            E[] enumConstants = (E[]) clazz.getEnumConstants();
            lst = Arrays.asList(enumConstants);                
        }
        return lst;
    }
```